# How can I properly assert an updated type between chained array methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an interface `QueryParam`

```
export default interface QueryParam {
  defaultValue?: boolean | number | string | string[];
  name: string;
  value?: boolean | number | string | string[];
}
```

When converting `QueryParam`s into a query string I begin by filtering out any that are `undefined` or where `value === defaultValue`.

```
  queryParams
    .filter(({ defaultValue, name, value }) => {
      if (value === undefined) {
        return false;
      }

      if (value === defaultValue) {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    });
```

Now I would like to chain a `.map()` call to convert each `QueryParam` to a `string` like so:

```
  queryParams
    .filter(({ defaultValue, name, value }) => {
      if (value === undefined) {
        return false;
      }

      if (value === defaultValue) {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    })
    .map(({ name, value }) => {
      ...
    });
```

However, in the call to `.map()` TypeScript considers `value` to still possibly be `undefined`. I would doubt there is a way to properly narrow the type between chained calls like this (if there is I would love to know what it is). But when I try to assert the updated type myself I get an error.

```
...
  .map(({ name, value }: { name: string; value: boolean | number | string | string[] }) => {
    return '';
  });
```

```
Argument of type '({ name, value }: { name: string; value: boolean | number | string | string[]; }) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: QueryParam, index: number, array: QueryParam[]) => string'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'QueryParam' is not assignable to type '{ name: string; value: string | number | boolean | string[]; }'.
      Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'string | number | boolean | string[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | string[]'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | string[]'.
```

I would like to find a way to properly assert the new type, or better yet, properly narrow the type without explicit overrides. I also don't really understand the error message fully, so info on that would be helpful as well.

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but the `.filter()` call can be simplified to `.filter(({ defaultValue, value }) => value !== undefined && value !== defaultValue)`

Comment: You're probably looking for a type predicate when filtering: https://tsplay.dev/Navv6m

Comment: @pink This does appear to be what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to the return type of the `filter` callback:

```
queryParams
    .filter((param): param is QueryParam & { value: ParamValue } => {
        return param.value !== undefined && param.value !== param.defaultValue;
    })
    .map(({ name, value }) => {
        value.toString(); // okay
    });
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwGpwDYFdoF4oBGA9kRhHAHZQA+UFWyBECNUAzsAgJYUDmrHbnwDaAXQDcAKEkQAHmCIJgUACYQAZnCwZlPYM00BjaAEUcCEPCTIoAb0lRHqjVp3psEAPwAuWIhTuOFJOdCgQvoI8vMFOAG6YOD5+1oEQUgC+0oZEFBxQAI7mlv7IbL5mzMXWYlD4YlKShZVWKGwOTgB06lw6zAAUfWAlAJS+Q9ZQXGxQFRYtNgBkdlDxHr7zqVDptQB8du0hjggQwFgIVOMoHas4UACEuPhYFGrdFBAqUAtLl8jXCdAHvhfh1Xq5gKkYo50sMDlAOsg4GABrZQsgIAAaFYArbDXb7Q5xAEdYBEADKnCifWG4igAHo6VAiABrOAgOEwqRAA)